# React Vite Project: Server Crashes with ESBuild Error

Tags: reactjs, npm, node-modules, vite, esbuild

I'm facing an issue while trying to set up a React Vite-based project using the latest version of Vite. Here's the sequence of steps I've taken:

First, I initialized the project using the command "npm create vite@latest", then I installed all the required dependencies without making any changes to the code.
However, when I attempt to run the project using npm run dev, the development server crashes, and I receive the following error message:

```
Failed to scan for dependencies from entries:
  C:...\index.html

 The service is no longer running
   at  C:...\\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1083:25
   at sendRequest ( C:...\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:699:14)
   at buildOrContextContinue ( C:...\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1081:5)
   at C:...\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:993:11
```

I'm using the latest version of npm and node

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you happen to be using an antivirus, it's advisable to uninstall it. In my case, I found it necessary to remove the SMADAV antivirus software, and this resolved the problem.